# How to set an assembly as a default reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clr

For each newly created C# project, the Visual Studio 2010 has put in some default references, such as System, System.Core, System.Xml, etc. The benefit of those default references is you can directly use them without adding them manually.

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a 3rd party assembly as the default reference, so that I do not need to add it each time I created a project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a custom project template for your needs. 
Take a look at the documentation [Creating Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx).
More specifically the [How to: Add References to Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185290).
You essentially modify the `.vstemplate` file so that it references your desired assemblies:

```
<TemplateContent>
    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>
                System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            </Assembly>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>
                System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            </Assembly>
        </Reference>
    </References>
    ...
</TemplateContent>
```

Having said that, you could modify the [OOB templates accordingly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1), if that is what you desire. They can be found at:
`\VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Language\Locale\`